# How do you factorise $5p^2+6p-8$ using the criss-cross method?

Tags: quadratics, factoring

I would like to factorise the quadratic expression that is $5p^2+6p-8$ **using the criss-cross method**; So far, it has been the only method taught to us.

The criss-cross method uses the factors of the constant term **($c$)** and multiplies them by the factors of the leading coefficient **($a$)** in an "x" or "cross" shape.

[image: a visual representation]

I've tried to solve it but my efforts are fruitless. If somebody could help to clarify the solution, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: The right hand side should multiply to 8 since that is the constant term. As written you have $5 \times 5 = 25 \neq 8$. Note that the criss-cross method is a "guess and test" method so you should expect it to fail with certain combinations of these divisors and have to try again. For example $2 \times 4 = 1 \times 8 = 8$ so you have to choose one for the right hand side and see if it works, then try again if it fails. Hopefully they'll teach you a better method soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$5p^2+6p-8$$

It's a bit hard to do the criss-cross method in Mathjax, so I might attempt to explain it with words. Bear with me...

**Step 1:** In a quadratic of the form $ax^2+bx+c$ we want to find $ac$. In your case, that is $5\cdot -8 = -40$.

**Step 2:** Consider the factors of $ac$ that add up to $b$. Factors of $-40$ are $\pm1,\pm2,\pm4,\pm5,\pm8,\pm10,\pm20,\pm40$. Only the pair of $-4, +10$ work. I.e. $-4+10=6$.

**Step 3:** Divide $a$ into your two factors. This step is harder to explain, but try to find factors of $a$ that divide into the factors of $ac$. In your example, $5$ divides into $10$, and $1$ divides into $4$, so what you have is $2$ and $4$. I will add a graphic at the end so you aren't lost.

**Step 4:** This is where you criss-cross. Your factors are the $p$ terms and your divided factors are the numbers. Geez, this is hard to explain. Here's a diagram.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much good sir! I thoroughly appreciate the diagram but your explanation wasn't too bad actually haha.

Answer (score 0):

To factor $5p^2 + 6p - 8$, we need two numbers with product $5 \cdot (-8) = -40$ and sum $6$.  Consider the factorizations of $-40$.
\begin{align*}
-40 & = -1 \cdot 40 & -40 & = 1 \cdot (-40)\\
    & = -2 \cdot 20 &  & = 2 \cdot (-20)\\
    & = \color{blue}{-4 \cdot 10} &  & = 4 \cdot (-10)\\
    & = -5 \cdot 8 & & = 5 \cdot (-8)
\end{align*}
Of these pairs of factors, only $-4$ and $10$ have a sum of $6$.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
5p^2 + 6p - 8 & = 5p^2 - 4p + 10p - 8 && \text{split the linear term}\\
              & = p(5p - 4) + 2(5p - 4) && \text{factor by grouping}\\
              & = (p + 2)(5p - 4) && \text{extract the common factor}
\end{align*}
In your criss-cross method, this amounts to matching $5p$ with $2$ to get $10p$ and $p$ with $-4$ to get $-4p$.  That said, I recommend using the method outlined above to eliminate guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a railroad sign style $X$ like you have done. In the top triangle you will write the product $ac$ from the quadratic of the form $y=ax^2+bx+c$, then in the bottom you will write the $b$ term. You should have $-40$ on top and $6$ on the bottom. Now you need to find two numbers which add to $6$ but multiply to $-40$. You will find these numbers are $-4$ and $10$ (by listing factors of $-40$ and seeing which ones must add up to $6$). After this step we write $5p^2-4p+10p-8$. Now we must factor this expression. We have 
\begin{equation}
5p^2-4p+10p-8 = 5p(p+2)-4(p+2) \\
=(5p-4)(p+2).
\end{equation}
This is our solution.